# Is there any linting that detects unresolved variables in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

In WebStorm, when a property does not exist on an object, it becomes underlined and when I hover on it gives me a tip indicating what's wrong. Is there something similar on VS Code?

[image]

I tried to install ESLint, together with the ESLint plugin, which helps me with a lot of errors, but this one seems to be skipped by ESLint.

- Is there any option that I cannot find that I have to activate to get the same behavior like in WebStorm?
- Or is there any other plugin that I have to install to make this work?
- If not, what options do I have to avoid typo's? (I mention I don't want to use TypeScript, because I want to teach someone JavaScript and adding TypeScript might be a bit too much for my purpose).

Here is my `.eslintrc.json` file:

```json
{
   "env": {
       "browser": true,
       "es2021": true
   },
   "extends": "eslint:recommended",
   "overrides": [
   ],
   "parserOptions": {
       "ecmaVersion": "latest"
   },
   "rules": {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is a native TypeScript extension that can be used to check JS files like there are TS files ([see official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript)):

1. *Go to File > Preferences > Settings*
2. Type *jsconfig*
3. Enable the setting *JS/TS Implicit Project Config: Check JS*
4. Disable *JS/TS Implicit Project Config: Strict Function Types* and *JS/TS Implicit Project Config: Strict Null Checks* (Optional, but you may want to do it, since there is no way to cast certain objects, e.g. `Element` to `HTMLElement`)